# Configure airflow with two different ports in same cluster?

Tags: airflow

How to create a airflow with two different ports in same cluster?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're speaking about the Airflow webserver process, since you didn't clarify, but you should be able to simply run multiple processes and just set the `AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__WEB_SERVER_PORT` environment variable for each process accordingly.